# Vintage turntable 50hz noise when touching tonearm

Tags: noise, ground

Hope someone can give some advice on this matter. I have a vintage Philips GP 808 turntable. There is this 50hz noise coming out from the speakers when I touch the tonearm. I don’t see any ground cable detached anywhere inside the chassis.
I am not a technician and can’t really read the schematics that I uploaded here.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ij8gw15vg80dham/ve_philips_gf_808_schematics_de.pdf?dl=0

This is a recording of the noise:

https://soundcloud.com/user-176288445/gf808-noise?si=e8254cebd190485c8f82b641a259cee9&utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing

Any clue?

Comment: Is there no earth cable connected from the turntable to the amplifier?

Comment: Is the tonearm a "metallic" one ?

Comment: No the amplifier is embedded in the turntable. No external amplifier is used. Yes the tonearm is metallic, I think aluminum.

Comment: Normally the TT would be grounded to the amplifier, usually by a separate wire from the two audio leads.

Comment: @user_1818839 there is no external amplifier. It’s inside the turntable. It works on its own.

Comment: Is it powered by a 3 pin mains lead? If not, that may be the problem.

Comment: The lead is the original one and has 2 pins. I don’t recall this problem in the past.

Comment: Does touching the chassis produce the same noise? If not the ground connection from chassis to tonearm has got broken somewhere.

Comment: Stop touching the tonearm!

Comment: @Finbarr no it doesn’t.

Comment: Well, the schematic shows 5 connections to the tonearm, four will be to the cartridge and the fifth will be to the body of the tonearm. Something has got disconnected somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the cartridge schematic.

[image]

Ground connection to the tonearm may be broken.

Continuity between tonearm and ground is to be checked.

Comment: That’s , as you pointed out, the cartridge schematics. The ground is for the cartridge not the tonearm.

Comment: In that case please check whether the white or the red wire is shorting with the metal tonearm.

Comment: to do so I would have to remove the cable entirely from the armtone. That’s not easy to do without causing a catastrophe. Anyway I will try something else and try to ground the armtone directly.

Comment: You may check for the short using a multimeter.

Comment: Nope nothing changes when grounding the armtone

Comment: I repeat - either the white or the red wire (signal wires) may be shorting with the tonearm. Should continuity between either of the signal wires and the tonearm is confirmed using a multimeter, you would need to rectify that to solve the problem.

Comment: checked. There’s no continuity. Installing the cartridge the clicking sound disappears. However the damndest thing now, when operating treble hum appears. There’s an internal chassis that houses the preamp and the pots, if you lift that chassis from the baseplate hum disappears. There is no trace of bare cables. Here a video of the humming. https://youtube.com/shorts/lj6DNhFwgHA?feature=share

Comment: In the above video is the audio fed from the turntable or a radio?

Comment: the audio is a led tv in the room, not coming from the TT. The turntable is in turntable mode.

Comment: Why not permanently lift that chassis from the base plate?

Comment: Because it’s screwed to the base plate and even putting some insulator on the bottom won’t prevent contact to the plate through the screws. Besides it shouldn’t act like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your body acts as an antenna. Tonearm sensor is sensitive enough to detect it.

Options:

1. Isolate the tonearm from you. Tape, heatshrink, polish spray. Easy.
2. isolate the tonearm from the circuitry. Take it apart and check where the tonearm comes into contact with the circuitry. Complicated.
3. Add 50hz + harmonics filter between the tonearm and the circuit, or circuit and the speaker. Very complicated.
4. Remove the mains from the house to remove the signal. Or at least put the turntable into a cage that isolates electric and magnetic fields. Expensive.

Comment: It'll have to be a big cage to fit the DJ as well, otherwise you're back to step 1 ;p

Comment: Option 5: ground the tonearm. The leads in it may be unshielded, because they must be really flexible to accept the rotation of the arm, and coaxial cable doesn't flex well. So the cables may be relying on the grounded metal of the arm to provide shielding.

Comment: Option 6: get a Spotify subscription.

Comment: It’s not the case.